# How to call (NPM) request multiple times in mocha before hook?

Tags: javascript, npm, mocha.js, npm-request

I would like to call request multiple time (2 times) in mocha before hook.  Is there a correct procedure/way to call them.  My current usage is like this and I get error done() called too many times.

```
describe('...', function(){
  before(function(done){
    request({
       ...
    }, function(err,res,body){
       ...
       done(); //also tried by removing it.
    });

    //request 2
    request({
       ...
    }, function(err,res,body){
       ...
       done();
    });
  });
  //it block follows
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to wait for all of the requests and only call done when they are all complete.

```
var requestAComplete = false, requestBComplete = false;

function checkDone() {
    if (requestAComplete && requestBComplete) {
        done();
    }
}

describe('...', function(){
  before(function(done){
    request({ ... }, function(err,res,body){
       ...
       requestAComplete = true;
       checkDone();
    });

    //request 2
    request({ ... }, function(err,res,body){
       requestBComplete = true;
       checkDone();
    });
  });
  //it block follows
});
```

Of course if you need more of them, you should use an array or a dictionary to track the statuses, and check with a loop. (or perhaps remove from the collection).

Alternatively, as a better but more advanced solution, wrap both requests into array of promises, convert into a promise of an array with `all` and call `done` when it resolves.